# Can anyone explain me the product of a matrix by its transpose?

Tags: matrices

Please solve it and explain it to me

$$ A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ -1 & 1\\ \end{bmatrix},\quad AA^T = \ ? $$

Comment: Do you know how to multiply matrices? It's simply multiplying A by its transpose.

Comment: Can you please briefly explain that.. with the answer

Comment: [Here's](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/mtrxmult.htm) an explanation on matrix multiplication and [here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) the wikipedia article for matrix transpose.

Answer (score 2):

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ -1 & 1\\ \end{bmatrix}, \qquad A^T=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1\\ 0 & 1\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Then $AA^T$ can be calculated by simply multiplying each row by each column

Answer (score 1):

You have $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ -1 & 1\\ \end{bmatrix}$

$A^T = \begin{bmatrix}1 &&-1\\0&&1\end{bmatrix}$

$A\cdot A^T=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ -1 & 1\\ \end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}1 &&-1\\0&&1\end{bmatrix}$

$ = \begin{bmatrix}1&&-1\\-1&&2\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Ok guys. . I got it. . Thankyou for your response. ..

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  a_{11} &a_{12} \\
  a_{21} &a_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  b_{11} &b_{12} \\
  b_{21} &b_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  a_{11}b_{11} + a_{12}b_{21} &a_{11}b_{12} + a_{12}b_{22} \\
  a_{21}b_{11} + a_{22}b_{21} &a_{21}b_{12} + a_{22}b_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
$$